# Find solution of a Cauchy problem for $\alpha \in R$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to find the solution for all $\alpha$

\begin{cases} 
y'(x) = e^{y(x)} (x-1) \\
y(0) = \alpha
\end{cases}

Do I study different value of $\alpha$?

Comment: $\alpha $ is unspecified ! Juste solve your ODE and see what happen (and if $\alpha $ need condition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning you can let $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ be arbitrary and find conditions on $\alpha$ along the way. Indeed, we see $$y'(x) = e^{y(x)}(x-1) \,\,\, \implies \,\,\, y'(x) e^{-y(x)} = x-1 \,\,\, \implies \,\,\, -\frac{d}{dx}e^{-y(x)} = x-1.$$ Integrating gives $$-\int^x_0 \frac{d}{dt} e^{-y(t)} dt = \int^x_0 (t-1)dt \,\,\, \implies \,\,\, -e^{-y(x)}+e^{-y(0)} = \frac{x^2}{2} - x.$$ But plugging in $y(0) = \alpha$, we see $$-e^{-y(x)} = \frac{x^2}{2} -x - e^{-\alpha}$$ or $$y(x) = -\log\left(e^{-\alpha} + x - \frac{x^2}{2} \right).$$ We didn't pick up any conditions on $\alpha$ along the way, so it appears that this solution works for any $\alpha$. However, note that this is only a local solution. Indeed, this will always work for small $x$, but when $x$ grows to the point that $e^{-\alpha} + x - x^2/2 = 0$, the solution will blow up.